# чем отличается . от -> в С++

Tags: c++

собственно вопрос влез в заголовок

Comment: тем же, чем и указатель отличается от ссылки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

оператор `a.b` обращается к объекту класса напрямую.
оператор `a->b` обращается по указателю, это является "Синтаксическим сахаром" к выражению `(*a).b`

Answer (score 7):

По Страуструпу ([Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием C++ 2 изд](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33852757/), прил. А.5, стр.1174):

> `x.m` - Доступ к члену класса; `x` должен быть объектом класса
>   `p->m` - Доступ к члену класса; `p` должен быть указателем на объект класса; эквивалентно `(*p).m`

Answer (score 6):

Они отличаются тем, что это *разные операторы*. Не ясно, откуда вообще мог возникнуть такой вопрос.

Оператор `->` является перегружаемым пользователем. Оператор `.` - не является перегружаемым пользователем.

*Встроенные* операторы `->` и `.` делают совершенно разные вещи. Оператор `->` требует указателя в левой части и первым делом разадресовывает указатель. Оператор `.` никакого разадресования указателя не делает.