# Какая разница между a.b и a->b?

Tags: c++

У меня есть код, с двумя вариантами, первый который работает с оператором `a.first` и второй который работает с оператором `a->first` для меня разницы нету, использовать первый или второй вариант.

Но в википедии написано что оператор `a->b` перегружаемый, какая будет разница между `a.b`, если это будет работать с циклами.

Я хочу знать точно `a.b` лучше будет чем `a->b` или значение не имеет?

Comment: Похожий [топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/931769/192978). А перегружаемость его означает, что оператор `->` можно переопределить в своих классах.

Comment: `a.b` и `a->b` не являются взаимозаменяемыми (если не лезть в экзотику). Так что ни о каком "лучше" тут речи быть не может. Вопрос в том, что именно вам *нужно*, а не в том, что лучше.

Comment: @AnT мне нужно выставить приоритеты, то есть если мне будет без разницы что использовать, я буду выбирать по приоритету.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как это - "нет разницы"?

Первое работает с самим объектом (ссылкой), второе - с указателем.

Типа

```
struct A {
    int b;
} a, * ptr;
```

Вы не сможете работать с `a->b`, как и с `ptr.b` - только `a.b` и `ptr->b` или `(*ptr).b`.

Если вы не переопределяете оператор `->` - то разницы никакой, это просто варианты записи одного и того же...

Comment: А если мне нужно будет передавать a.b или a->b в буфер тогда что будет лучше?
это уже второй вопрос конечно, но цель также :)

Comment: Выставлю галочку Harry, его ответ более информативный, он затронул разницу между указателем и объектом, конечно я пока не понял. Если указатель в цикле, значит он меняет переменную вне цикла и с ней можно взаимодействовать. Очень много таких мелочей и неясностей.

Answer (score 5):

`a->b` подразумевает `(*a).b`

То есть `->` используется, если у нас есть указатель на объект и мы хотим получить его поле.

Comment: Пока я понял что (*a).b выглядит намного больше чем a.b, интересно как компилятор переводит это в машинный код.

Answer (score 2):

Вы говорите

> "У меня есть код, с двумя вариантами,... "

Нам неизвестно какой код у вас имеется. Например, если у меня(у вас) имеется такие структуры:

```
struct B {
    int first = 5;  
};
struct A {
    B b;
    int first = b.first + 1;
    B* operator->() { return &b; }
};
```

то вполне можно записать два варианта одного и того же кода:

```
A a;
//первый вариант
int version1() { 
    //...       
    return a.first - 1;
}
// второй вариант
int version2() {  
    //...   
    return a->first ;
}
```

1. Результатом первой функции является значение `first` из структуры `A`(A::first == B::first` == 6) минус 1.
2. Результатом второй функции будет уже `B::first == 5`.
   Оба варианта будут работать с тем же значением, содержащимся в разных обьектах.

   Так что, все таки, выражения `a.first` и `a->first` могут существовать одновременно и иметь разный результат

Comment: Мне больше интересно на низком уровне, почти на ассемблерном коде в чем будет отличия. Если кто знает и опишет разницу, на низком уровне, я буду признателен.
Предположим у нас память программы не больше 100 кб, например калькулятора, какой код будет занимать больше памяти.
Потом еще важно, код который будет меньше, он работает быстрей или медленней, я уверен что разница в скорости должна быть. Навряд ли компилятор компилирует код одинаково.

Answer (score 1):

Перегрузка `->` имеет смысл когда объект подразумевает абстрактную ссылку на что-то.

```
# include <iostream>
class Int {
public:
  int i;
};

template  < class T >
class Link {
public :
  Link ( T & t ):secret(&t){}
  T * operator -> (void) { return secret ; }
private :
  T * secret ;
};

void f (  Link<Int> l  ) {
  l->i = 7 ;
  }

int main(){
  Int i;
  f(i);
  std::cout<<"i.i="<<i.i<<"\n";
  }
```

Это всего-лишь для красоты, чтобы понять, что объект **Link** на что-то указывает.

Comment: Очень запутанный код, не надо такое писать :)

Comment: Согласен, я ж не заставляю вас писать на c++. ;)

Comment: Тоже верно, на с++ пишут только психи :)

Comment: Дополнение: *Перегрузка -> имеет смысл когда объект подразумевает абстрактную ссылку на что-то..*, как, например, в умных указателях. Имхо, пример с умным указателем немного понятнее, чем с абстрактным линком