# Что значит знак -> в c++?

Tags: c++, указатели, стандарт

Или хотя бы как он называется, чтобы про него погуглить.

Comment: Это оператор косвенного обращения к члену, как по-английски - не помню. Есть еще и такой `->*` =)

Comment: Вот они https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

Comment: похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/931769/192978

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Оператор косвенного обращения.

Смысл примерно такой - например, в структуре/класса типа

```
struct T {
    int t;
    ...
```

вы обращаетесь к полю (члену) `t` объекта `T obj` как

```
obj.t
```

Если у вас есть указатель на объект `T* ptr`, то к полю объекта, на который указывает `ptr`, вы обращаетесь как

```
(*ptr).t
```

или - смотрим внимательно :) - как к

```
ptr->t
```

Вот, собственно, что это такое...